# unable to install phpmyadmin in RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, yum, php, phpmyadmin

I am using **red hat 6.0 Linux**.Currently **php 5.3.2** is installed.I want to install **phpMyAdmin** in it.for that **php5.5** is required.

I already installed **epel ,remi repository** in my system.
I am trying to upgrade php version, but it fails because of dependency check.

when I am trying to update the software (System--> Administration --> Software Update),it failed due to **Transaction Error.**

when I trying to issue command

```
yum update
```

it also failed and gives following errors

```
Error: Package: libzip5-1.5.1-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: php-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.61-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)
Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.61-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
Error: Package: php-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am not able to understand whats wrong with the system, which packages really required to install phpmyadmin.